# Launch application from nodes

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, command-prompt

I am developing a nodejs application. From this application I would like to launch other desktop applications (windows and Mac) with command arguments.
The only way I know this can be done for windows is as follows:

Child_process.exec("start someapp.exe arg1 arg2", {cwd: "directory containing someapp.exe"}, callback...)

Two problems:
- this doesn't work on a Mac, "start" keyword doesn't work on a Mac (yes yes, there are no exes on macs)
- the handle to the process returned by exec, is not the process of the application launched. I believe it is the handle to the cmd.exe application.

So, does anyone know a better way of launching apps from nodejs, with the UI. Please remember I need to launch a desktop application, and would like to see the app.

Next, does anyone know how this can be achieved on a Mac.

Finally, if this is at all possible can I somehow get the handle to the process or at least the process id of the process launched.

Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option is to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn) module to run applications, it is cross platform so will help you out on Mac.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't return the handle to the process launched. I will give it a try, thanks.